# Render HTML from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a plugin in which UI can only be rendered within `JavaScript`.
It's been long when I last worked in JS.

So wanted to know if there is better approach then writing:

```
document.getElementById("XXXX").innerHTML....
```

Any approach (or even a framework) is welcome.

Thank You

P.S - Plugin I'm writing is for *sonarqube*.

Comment: Try React JS, or Angular

Comment: If you're going to work with JSON data, use a template engine, something like Handlebars

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery then $(selector).html("...") does the work.

Comment: Yea, its working mate.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is `document.createElement` combined with `Node.appendChild` (the element just created)

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Historically innerHTML has been favored due to better performance, but if I recall correctly the difference is barely noticeable and in my humble opinion it's much prettier.

Example:

```
var container = document.getElementById("myContainer");
var myParagraph = document.createElement("p");
var hello = document.createTextNode("Hello World.");

myParagraph.appendChild(hello);
container.appendChild(myParagraph);
```